# NodeJS recursive promise rally

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, recursion, promise

I am trying to fetch details from rally by traversing through each subprojects.

But I am not getting anything printed though I have a console.log(output) at the end. When I print output immediately after pushing into the array, I can see the values. What am I doing wrong here?

```
function getProjects(projectRef, output) { 
    var deferred = Promise.defer();
    callAc(projectRef, ['FormattedID', 'Name', 'Children', 'Parent', 'TeamMembers'], function(result) {
        result.Object.Results.forEach(function(item) {
            output.push(item.Name);
            getProjects(item.Children._ref.split('webservice/v2.0')[1], output)
                .then(function() {
                    deferred.resolve();
                });
        });
    });
    return deferred.promise;
}

function callAc(ref, parameters, callback) {
    restApi.get({
        ref: ref,
        fetch: parameters,
        scope: {
            workspace: '/workspace/XXXX'
        },
        requestOptions: {}
    }).then(function(result) {
        callback(result);
    }).fail(function(errors) {
        console.log(errors);
    });
}

var output = [];
var projectRef = '/Project/<some_project_id>/Children';
getProjects(projectRef, output)
    .then(function() {
        console.log('fetched all projects');
        console.log(output);
    });
```

Source: https://mostafa-samir.github.io/async-recursive-patterns-pt2/

Comment: If I'm reading your code correctly, `callback` does not get called when your `restApi` call fails.  If that's the case, the promise created in the last call to `getProjects` would never resolve, so your overall promise created in the first call to `getProjects` would never resolve, so your `then` callback would never get called.

Answer (score 0):

First, You are looking at the wrong tutorial. It is from 2015. Today, standard [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) doesn't have fail() or defer(). Fail handler lives in the second parameter of the then().

Another problem is callback. One of the purpose of Promise is to reduce callback. I relocated the callback into then().

<del>Last, there is a infinite loop in the original code, where I added the recursion termination 1==0.</del>

```
var restApiget = function(ref) {
    console.log('restApiget', ref);
    var child = childGen.next().value;
    return Promise.resolve(child);
}

var childMaker = function* () {
    yield ['1', '2'];
    yield ['4', '5'];
    yield ['6', '7'];
    yield ['8', '9'];
    while (true)
        yield [];
}
childGen = childMaker();

function getProjects(projectRef, output) {
    return callAc(projectRef, ['FormattedID', 'Name', 'Children', 'Parent', 'TeamMembers'])
        .then(function(res) {
            output.push(projectRef);
            console.log('callAc', 'then', res);
            var promises = [];
            res.forEach((i) => {
                promises.push(getProjects(i, output));
            });
            if (promises.length > 0) {
                return Promise.all(promises);
            }
            return Promise.resolve(res);
        });
}

function callAc(ref, parameters, callback) {
    return restApiget(ref);
}

var output = [];
var projectRef = 'root';

getProjects(projectRef, output)
    .then(function(res) {
        console.log('fetched all projects');
        console.log('mess up', res);
        console.log(output);
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        console.log('catch', err);
    })
```

In this example, the "project" structure is,

```
       root 
      /    \
     1      2
    / \    / \
   4   5  6   7
  / \    
 8   9
```

Comment: i have a forEach in my code, how you suggest to go about with that?

Comment: and it's not infinite loop, because in every iteration am passing children's reference.. so at one point there will not be any children

Comment: Sorry I didn't catch the forEach loop at the first time, and thought it was infinite loop. I updated the answer. I use a `Promise.all` to handle the `forEach`. However, the downside is, it will mess up the `res`. If you can accept using `output` for capture the result, it should be fine.

Comment: thanks for the update, i should not keep the project structure in code as i am having around 1000 projects...